# How 2nd level cache works with getAll & get in gorm?

Tags: hibernate, caching, grails, grails-orm

Hi have set 'cache true' for domain class which means cache is enabled

```
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```

Now if I say `DomianClass.get(1)`  -- it doesn't hit the database but when I use `DomianClass.getAll()` it hits the database.

Isn't `DomianClass.getAll()` fetches from cache? why does it hit the database everytime?
Is there any option to fetch all the records from 2nd level cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible for the hibernate 2nd level cache to determine if "all" exists in the cache or not. Let's walk through why with some examples.

### Case #1

DomainClass.get(1) asks cache if 1 exists. If so, return it, if not hit the db, cache it and return it. Further requests for 1 from the cache will return from the cache.

### Case #2

DomainClass.getAll() asks cache if "all" exists. The cache then has to think "What does all mean?" and the only logical response is "I don't know, but the database does."

Now in case #2 you /might/ be tempted to think that if you made a request for "all" then the cache could cache that response. However, that's a different kind of cache than the 2nd level cache for hibernate.

Put simply, the 2nd level cache is for instances, indexed by domain class and identity.

Comment: 1 things is if I say getAll(1,2,3), that is if I provide ids then also it doesn't fetch from cache. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: That's a very good question. I can't dig through github right now to find out why but I am sure there is a technical reason. You might want to ask on the Grails mailing list.